# Rails timestamps, See how much time passed since last time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

In my app I want to print out the duration of time I spent from I made the model until I updated it.

**So if I have the value**

:created_at set to 2016-04-13 14:00:49 UTC
and 
:updated_at set to 2016-04-13 15:05:49 UTC

I want to print out that it took 1hour and 5minutes. (or just 01.05).
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this was downvoted, though a little googling would probably have gotten you to the right answer fairly quickly.

What you're looking for is called `time_ago_in_words`

Here is the doc http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_ago_in_words

And usage is:

```
time_ago_in_words @object.created_at
time_ago_in_words @object.updated_at
```

If you want to use it the console to play with it, make sure you preface it with `helper` so it's loaded into console

e.g.

```
helper.time_ago_in_words @object.created_at
```

## update

For checking between 2 dates, not just one date from right now, then you can use `distance_of_time_in_words`

```
distance_of_time_in_words(@object.created_at, @object.updated_at)
```

That gives words like

> 12 days ago

If you're ONLY looking for hours, and nothing else then you can use basic subtraction and division

```
@object.updated_at.to_i - @object.created_at.to_i) / 60 / 60
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw this and also got alot of countdown results when I googled. But I don't want the time from now. I want the time between starttime and updatetime. I've tried just subtracting them but it seems like it doesn't work because it prints out the days too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 diff =@object.updated_at.to_time.to_i - @object.created_at.to_time.to_i
    hour = "#{diff / 3600}:#{(diff % 3600) / 60}"
```